# Cannot load value of "multiple line of text" using COM in javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-clientobject

The column name is "Dialog Box". I tried this

```
                var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                var targetList = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("myList");
                var targetListItem = targetList.getItemById(_spGetQueryParam('id'));
                context.load(targetListItem, "Dialog Box");
                context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onStatusQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, onStatusQueryFailed));

                function onStatusQuerySucceeded() {

                    alert(targetListItem.get_item("Dialog Box"));
                }

                function onStatusQueryFailed(sender, args) {
                    alert("failed Dialog Box");                                            
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Dialog Box" is title, you should try with internal name. You can use SharePoint manager to get internal name of column. But to make sure create new column without space and with non existing name and try to get value. Column name without space have same internal name if its not exist.

Comment: I tried with another column named "Status" and it succeeded. So you are right it might be the space. How do you get the internal name ? Please, describe.

Comment: You can use SharePoint Manager tool that you can download. In Sharepoint Manager you can navigate to list where you added column.Inside list navigate to fields. Open field and there you can see all property of field.

Comment: OR you can also try with  give _x0020_ for each space. In Your case try with Dialog_x0020_Box. This is how internal name is generated.But I am not very sure for this solution.